# How to inject a class or a static method?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, koin

How do I inject a complete class or a static method of a class?

Let's say I would like to use the static `PhoneNumberUtils.compare(number1, number2)` method in my Android app.

How would I use/inject this method with Koin? Would I just pass the parameters to a factory definition and then inject the result of the `compare` method? Or should I avoid here Dependency Injection here at all?

Comment: You could inject a strategy interface (e.g., `PhoneNumberResolutionStrategy`) that offers an API relevant to your scenario. One implementation of that strategy might use `PhoneNumberUtils.compare()`, while others might not.

Comment: I couldn't understand your question properly. Could you please describe more about what exactly you are trying to achieve here?

Comment: @BirjuVachhani I wonder what would be the best way to handle static functions like `Uri.parse(string)` or `DateFormat.is24HourFormat(context)` with DI. Do you inject them somehow as functions, do you call them with a parameter and just inject the result, or don't you use DI for those "helper" functions at all? I am pretty new to DI, and maybe I wonder more when to use DI (and when not) instead of how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Generally we don't use DI for static functions.

You should DI where you have create new instances of classes. So, as an example, you need to access `SharedPreferences` in your `Activity` or `Fragment`, then you create a new instance by calling `getSharedPreferences()`. So, this can be moved to DI and can be injected in your `Activity` or `Fragment`.

Another example is that you need your Retrofit Service instance in some of your classes, then instead of creating them every time when you need it, you can move it to DI and then inject the same instance every time you need it.

All that means is you use DI when there's a need to create a new instance of a class.